# Capitalization of Section Titles

Tags: capitalization

How to capitalize the words of a section title? In particular, when Should I capitalize the word "to?" Sometimes I see it capitalized and sometimes not.

Comment: I usually do not capitalize words like prepositions if they are four words or less. I don't think you need to capitalize "to."

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, Check with reviewers or publishers, who sometimes have standards for such things. Generally speaking though, both forms are acceptable. I.e., this:

> A Caption For Us To Consider

is no better or worse that this:

> A Caption for Us to Consider

I tend to prefer the second (as a matter of taste), but I've seen both used. If the place you're submitting the work has published standards, you should follow them; if they don't, then don't be surprised if they reformat your headers to fit some internal guideline.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, the first word and all significant words in a title are capitalized.  Thus if you were to have a title that uses the famous quote from Hamlet (also has the word "to" in it twice to demonstrate) we get:

> To Be or Not to Be

Here, "Be" and "Not" are capitalized because they are significant to the title ("To exist" or "Not" being the original purpose of quote).  The first "to" is also capitalized because it is the first rule while "or", a conjunctive word, and both instances of "to", a particle for the infinitive form of "Be" are grammatically important but not thematically.